# What are the Peirce's axioms of arithmetic and how do they relate to the Peano axioms?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, mathematical-logic

I will be glad if someone who has seen Peirce's paper could summarily describe here  Peirce's axioms and describe their relation to Peano's.

Comment: Here is a an open source for [On the Logic of Number](https://arisbe.sitehost.iu.edu/menu/library/bycsp/lognum.htm). Peirce's "axioms" are informal, unlike Peano's, and are phrased as definitions, e.g. "*an infinite system may be defined as one in which from the fact that a certain proposition, if true of any number, is true of the next greater, it may be inferred that that proposition if true of any number is true of every greater*" is induction. But the content is similar. See [Shields's dissertation](https://research.library.fordham.edu/dissertations/AAI8111317/) for commentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C.S.Peirce, [On the logic of number (1881)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2369151.pdf).

Peirce's system is equivalent to Peano axiomatization.

> A discrete system is one in which every quantity greater than another is next greater than some quantity (that is, greater than without being greater than something greater than).

> An infinite system is one in which any quantity greater than x can be reaclhed from x by successive steps to the next greater (or less) quantity than the one already arrived at.

> we may say that an infinite class is one in which if it is true that every quantity next greater than a quantity of a given class itself belongs to that class, then it is true that every quantity greater than a quantity of that class belongs to that class.

> The minimum number is called one.

The language is cumbersome but the basic "ingredients" are there: an initial number; the successor function; induction.

Then the standard recursive definitions of $+$ and $\times$ follow:

> By $x + y$ is meant, in case $x = 1$, the number next greater than $y$ [i.e. $s(y)$, the *successor* of $y$]; and in other cases, the number next greater than $x' + y$, where $x'$ is the number next smaller than $x$ [i.e. $s(x)+y=s(x+y)$].

Induction is explicitly used in the proof of theorems, starting from the associative principle of addition:

> The proof in each case will consist in showing, first, that the proposition is true of the number one, and second, that if true of the number $n$ it is true of the number $1 + n$, next larger than $n$.